# No consigo que se muestre imagenes en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una vista que muestra una lista de plantas.
Previo a esta, muestro una foto de un helecho con este código:

```
<img src="helecho.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid red">
```

La foto la he colocado en el mismo directorio que el documento PHP con mi vista (index.blade.php).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no se muestra la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que podria estar haciendo mal? De hecho, he probado la misma imagen en un html aislado y si se ve.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: las imágenes debes copiarlas a la carpeta public

Comment: Solo utiliza en el atributo src lo siguiente. src="{{ asset('tu ruta') }}" Esto siempre y cuando estés utilizando blade como motor de plantillas. En caso de que estes renderizando componentes en el cliente  deberas de utilizar rutas absolutas( Toda La ruta de la imagen incluyendo dominio).

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente este seria un ejemplo de agregar la imagen, en las vistas blade. de igual manera tienes que colocoar tu imagen en el directorio de public.

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('directory/name_of_image_file.file_format')}}"
```

Comment: (proyecto laravel)/public es donde dejo en principalmente las imagenes.

Comment: @JualL Y una vez tengo hecho eso, escribo en la vista <img src="{{ $plantas->foto }}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid green" class="img-responsive img-rounded" >

Comment: Y así consigo ver las imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado, aunque podria verse como una chapuza.
Fue poner este cambio en el codigo:

```
<img src="http://localhost/flora/resources/views/vegetal/helecho.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid red">
```

Y listo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Miguel es una chapuza porque es una ruta que solo se va a ver en local y con tu configuración actual. Las imágenes son lo que Laravel llama "assets" como los ficheros JS, CSS, etc. Colocalos en la carpeta `public` y usa el helper **asset** para cargarlos, por ejemplo:
`<img src="{!! asset('images/helecho.jpg') !!}">` donde la imagen se sitúa dentro del subdirectorio `public/images/` es decir que con el helper `asset`se accede directamente a los ficheros situados en la carpeta `public`. Mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140038/20709

Comment: coloca la carpeta de imagenes dentro de la carpeta "public". public/vegetal/helecho.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en ninguna respuesta indican que hay que agregar las imagenes orgranizadas en una carpeta dentro del directorio public/img. Lo mismo aplica para los estilos de CSS, public/img. [image: Directorio proyecto laravel, public]

Posteriormente, deberás indicar en el parámetro src `/img/(NOMBRE_DE_TU_CARPETA)/(NOMBRE_DE_TU_IMAGEN.EXTENSION)` [image: Ejemplo src]